# Node unhandel promises and imports oop

Tags: mysql, node.js, oop

My code have an obj name SQLFeeter that need to do the sql interaction which get the data post it and pass it along I have some problem which is one imports. The babel doesn't work second while I try to get the data and pass it

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql')

/*
--------------------------------------
This will handel all get requests
--------------------------------------
*/
/* 
//sqlInteractuin test
const SqlDataGetter = require('../../sqlInteraction/GetData');
//import  SqlDataGetter  from "./sqlInteraction/GetData";
let SqlGetter = new SqlDataGetter
*/

class SqlDataGetter {
  constructor()
  {
    this.con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "XXX",
      password: "XXX",
      database: "APP"
    });
  }

  GetClients()
  {    
    let con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "XXX",
      password: "AAA",
      database: "APP"
    });
      let resultFromSql = null;   
      con.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          let sql_query = "SELECT * FROM contacts"
          con.query(sql_query , function (err, result, fields) {
              if (err) throw err;
              //console.log(fields);
              console.log(result);
              resultFromSql =  result;
          });
          return resultFromSql;
      });
  }
  Tester()
  {
      //return this.con
      //console.log(this.con)
      return 'hello world'
  }

}



router.get('/' , async (req , res) =>
{
    //Need to make an obj that take the data and do all the querys
    res.status(200).send("DataBack");
});

router.get('/Clients' , async (req , res) =>
{
  let sql_getter = new SqlDataGetter();
  const Clients = sql_getter.GetClients();
  console.log(Clients);
  SqlDataGetter.GetClients()
  res.status(200);
  res.send({ respond : Clients});
});
```

While I am trying to run this at first it works on stand alone but when I create the ajax request it saying GetClients is not a function. And when I try to make the connection to be a property of this object as this.con when I activate this.con.query undifend property query of undifend.

Comment: Use `promise-mysql` instead of `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `promise-mysql` instead of `mysql` then you'll get promises from the method calls, which will make it easier to work with:

```
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');
```

Then your class would look like this:

```
class SqlDataGetter {
  constructor() {
    this.conPromise = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "XXX",
      password: "XXX",
      database: "APP"
    });
  }
  async GetClients() {
    const con = await this.conPromise;
    const result = await con.query("SELECT * FROM contacts");
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Finally, you'd use that class as follows:

```
router.get('/Clients' , async (req , res) => {
  let sql_getter = new SqlDataGetter();
  const clients = await sql_getter.GetClients();
  console.log(clients);
  res.status(200);
  res.send({ respond : clients});
});
```